# RESTful post in Oracle Service Bus 12C

Tags: osb

I will be receiving an XML payload and I need to convert the XML into JSON and post the JSON payload using REST POST operation.

I could not find any example over the internet that does POST.
Can someone let me know the steps to achieve this task?

Below is the sample JSON payload that I need to POST
{
"Type": "File",
"FileName": "attachment.txt",
"Title": "REST Invoice related attachment",
"Description": "REST Invoice related attachment",
"Category": "From Supplier",
}

Thank you